# Share parameters in Pipeline sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I want to use Pipeline from sklearn for my own estimators. For example I have some shema: A -> B -> C -> D. And I want to transfer/share parametr from B to C and from B to D. How I can to do this?

Comment: Not clear. Please explain more about share parameters.

Comment: Function 'fit' in estimator B count some data (parameters), which are needed in fit for C and for fit in D estimator

Comment: @АлександрШурыгин Can you be explicit about what you want to use as parameters for what functions?

Comment: Ok. What you are describing is out of scope of the pipeline. A pipeline should take some data in, output some new data that is used as input to next part. No other thing should be a dependency for the next part, other than the data returned by previous part.

Comment: So, no. The inbuild scikit-learn Pipeline cannot do that. But you can very easily make your own custom wrapper or pipeline that can do this.